# Java coin flip with user entered variables

Tags: java, coin-flipping

I am trying to create a java program which accepts a user entered number and then flips a coin that many times and then displays how many heads or tails have been flipped so far. 
My problem comes when I can't figure out how to make the program flip the coin the number of times the user says to, any help?

```
package E1;
import java.util.Scanner;
public class E1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) { 
        int hCount = 0;
        int tCount = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("How many coins should be tossed?");
        input.nextInt();
        if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
            System.out.println("Heads");
            hCount++;
        } else {
            System.out.println("Tails");
            tCount++;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Break your problem down into smaller steps... First, you're never capturing the input. Second, do you know how to write a regular  loop?

Comment: Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236)

Comment: Also, as @cricket_007 indicated, images of code are not helpful. Please include the code as text.

Comment: Added code and removed image, sorry. I do not know how to write a loop, no.

Comment: A `for` loop allows you to repeat an action a specified number of times. See the documentation here: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html

Comment: Tried it, can't make it use the variable from the scanner.

Comment: Also in the Java documentation is how to read user input... You read a nextInt, but how would you **get** that number? Just to print it, for example? It is expected you do some research before asking a question here, otherwise, you're not really learning on your own

Comment: Save the user input in a **variable** like `int amount = input.nextInt();`. Then place the flipping inside a regular **for** loop like `for (int i = 0; i < amount; i++) { ... }`. Google both terms and you'll find plenty of examples and explanation.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a dialog window, the User indicates the number of times and then you can work around that, look:

```
    package E1;
    import java.util.Scanner;
    import javax.swing.*; // shows the dialogs windows

        public class E1 {
        public static void main(String[] args){

        // This Dialog Window will ask the User how many times the coin will be tossed
                int n_of_flips = JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, 
                    "Please indicate how many times you wish to flip the coin",
                    "Coin Flip",
                    JOptionPane.QUESTION_MESSAGE);


           // the while loop
           int x = 0;
           while(x<= n_of_flips){
            // your code here:
            if (Math.random() < 0.5)
                {
                System.out.println("Heads");
                        x++;
            }else{
                System.out.println("Tails");
                            x++;
            } // END while loop

       } // END public static void

    } // END of E1
```

For more information google "JOptionPane Java", you can also display your results in a dialog window. Have fun :

Comment: If you like the answer you can give a vote, let me know if it works :)

Comment: Dialog box? Why?

Comment: It's an option, it's a way to create a Graphical User Interface. Making GUIs is fun and Java has good tools to do so

Answer (score 0):

I suggest set package name in lower case as it's a wide and good practice.

Look at this, it could be what you want:

```
package e1;

import java.util.Scanner;

public class E1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int hCount = 0;
        int tCount = 0;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("How many coins should be tossed? ");
        int coinsCount = input.nextInt();
        for (int i=0; i < coinsCount; i++) {
            if (Math.random() < 0.5) {
                System.out.println("Heads");
                hCount++;
            } else {
                System.out.println("Tails");
                tCount++;
            }
        }
        System.out.println("Heads: "+hCount+", Tails: "+tCount);
    }
}
```